# How to insert a teaser breaker in the hexo post?

Tags: markdown, hexo

Any idea how to add a teaser breaker or line breaker in the post in hexo?

So the list view which is by default the homepage will show for each post just what's before the teaser breaker? Seems by default, it shows everything in the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the theme you use.

if the theme does support it, in your post you can do:

> ```
> title: post title
> ---
> This part is the excerpt, get it with the <%- post.excerpt %>
> <!-- more --> 
> This is the rest of the post. You can get it with <%- post.more %>
> ```
>
> https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/1143#issuecomment-102247129